# "Unable To Load Client Print Control" - SSRS Printing problems again

Tags: reporting-services, printing

Please forgive me as my head is spinning.  I have tried so many solutions to this issue, that I'm almost not sure where I am at this point.

At this point in time I have these issues in my Production, Test, and Dev environments.  For simplicity sake, I will just try to get it working in Dev first.  Here is my setup:

Database/Reporting Server (Same server):
Windows Server 2003 SP2
SQL Server 2005 SP3

Development Box:
Windows 7
Visual Studio 2008 SP1
SQL Server 2008 SP1 (not being used in this case, but wanted to include it in case it is relative)
Internet Explorer 8

Details:

```
* I have a custom ASP.NET application that is using ReportViewer to access reports on my Database/Reporting Server.
* I am able to connect directly to Report Manager and print with no trouble.
* When I view source on the page with ReportViewer, it says I'm am using version 9.0.30729.4402 .
* The classid of the rsclientprint.dll that keeps getting installed to my c:\windows\downloaded program files directory is {41861299-EAB2-4DCC-986C-802AE12AC499}.
* I have tried taking the rsclientprint.cab file from my Database/Reporting Server and installing it directly to my Development Box and had no success.  I made sure to unregister the previously installed dll first.
```

I feel like I have read as many solutions as I can, and so I turn to you for some assistance.  Please let me know if I can provide further details that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am cross posting the solution I received on MSDN.  I hope it helps someone else.

> Hi mamorgan1,
>
> From your description, I notice you
>   are using Report Viewer with version
>   9.0.30729.4402, and SQL Server Reporting Serivces 2005 with SP3.
>
> RS Client Print control is an ActiveX
>   control which uses a ClassID to check
>   if the ActiveX is installed on the
>   client. By default, the ClassID for
>   SQL Server Reporting Services SP3 is
>   41861299-EAB2-4DCC-986C-802AE12AC499.
>   However, Report Viewer 9.0.30729.4402
>   would like the ClassID
>   0D221D00-A6ED-477C-8A91-41F3B660A832.
>   RSClientPrint control has been updated
>   after applying Cumulative Update #8
>   for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3.
>
> So, please apply Cumulative Update #8
>   for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3  to
>   solve the issue.
>
> For more information about Cumulative
>   Update #8 for SQL Server 2005 Service
>   Pack 3, please see:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978915/en-us
>
> If you have any more questions, please
>   feel free to ask.
>
> Thanks, Jin ChenJin Chen - MSFT

Comment: We had this problem, however after we got the "Cannot load Print Client" error to go away, the attempt at printing would cause the browser to hang, and then soon after just lock up.  What we also found was the firewall was knocking out the EMF header which is the format used to create the image.  See this post for more info: http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/printing-in-reporting-services-hangs-49301.shtml this is security issue: http://www.checkpoint.com/defense/advisories/public/2006/cpai-18-Feb.html